# Why "t1 inner join t2" and "t1 inner join t3" is fast, but "t1 inner join t2 inner join t3" is 265 times slower?

Tags: mysql

I create a mysql server using bitnami WAMP on my PC, and create two tables table_a and table_b with the flowing SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `table_b` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

when I run:

```
select 
    t1.id, 
    t1.date,
    t1.value
from
    (
    select 
        id,
        c_id,
        date,
        value
    from 
        table_a
    where
        id >= '7000'
    and id <  '10000'
    )
    t1
inner join
    (
    select 
        id, 
        c_id 
    from 
        table_b 
    where 
        status = 1
        id >= '7000'
    and id <  '10000'
    group by 
        id, 
        c_id
    order by null
    ) 
    t2
on 
    t1.id = t2.id
and t1.c_id = t2.c_id
```

it costs 0.031 sec,
here is the explain plan:
[image: explain plan]

when i run:

```
select 
    t1.id, 
    t1.date,
    t1.value
from
    (
    select 
        id,
        c_id,
        date,
        value
    from 
        table_a
    where
        id >= '7000'
    and id <  '10000'
    )
    t1
inner join
(
    select 
        id
    from 
        (

            SELECT 
                id, 
                count(*) as times 
            FROM 
                table_b 
            where 
                status = 1
            and id >= '7000'
            and id <  '10000'   
            group by 
                id 
            order by null

        )
        t 
    where 
        times >= 2
) 
t3
on t1.id = t3.id
```

it still costs 0.031 sec,
here is the explain plan:
[image: explain plan]

but when I run t1 inner join t2 inner join t3, it costs 8.375 sec, here is the sql:

```
select 
    t1.id, 
    t1.date,
    t1.value
from
    (
    select 
        id,
        c_id,
        date,
        value
    from 
        table_a
    where
        id >= '7000'
    and id <  '10000'
    )
    t1
inner join
    (
    select 
        id, 
        c_id 
    from 
        table_b 
    where 
        status = 1
        id >= '7000'
    and id <  '10000'
    group by 
        id, 
        c_id
    order by null
    ) 
    t2
on 
    t1.id = t2.id
and t1.c_id = t2.c_id

inner join
(
    select 
        id
    from 
        (

            SELECT 
                id, 
                count(*) as times 
            FROM 
                table_b 
            where 
                status = 1
            and id >= '7000'
            and id <  '10000'   
            group by 
                id 
            order by null

        )
        t 
    where 
        times >= 2
) 
t3
on t1.id = t3.id
```

here is the explain plan:
[image: explain plan]

What is the cause of the problem?

Comment: Can you add explain plans for all your queries please.

Comment: As @P.Salmon stated without `Explain...` plans of all these queries, it is difficult to compare. Still, you can get some of the explanation for your problem from this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/247171/160363

Comment: Not really an answer for your question, but maybe suggestion for work around - try creating temp tables (t1, t2) and (t1, t3) and inner join them together - see how fast that would be. It might give you some answer regarding the best solution.

Comment: Hi  @P.Salmonm, thanks for your comment, I've added the Explain... plans now.

Comment: Hi  @Madhur Bhaiya, thanks for your comment, I've added the Explain... plans now.

Comment: The empty columns 'possible_keys', and 'key' in the explain plans is one of the reasons for this slowness. If you add a key on `id` (because that's the link between the tables), the query should run faster.

Comment: @user3315198 To understand "why slow", you will need to understand [Nested Loop Join Algorithm](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/nested-loop-joins.html). Basically last query is doing more Disk I/O lookup within the nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your tables lack indexes.  An index on the join key is needed for joins to perform well.  For the first query, you are saved by MySQL who automatically creates an index (auto_key0) on the temporary table where the result of the subquery is stored.  The query plan for query 2 surprises me.  I would have expected a similar plan as for query 1, and I do not understand how the shown plan can perform as well as reported.  Also, I do not understand why you do not get an auto_key in the third query.

Regardless, for InnoDB tables, it is recommended to always define a primary key.  In your case, I guess `id` you be the primary key in your tables.  Your queries would also benefit from a secondary index on `c_id` .